# argparse - Build back command line

Tags: python, argparse

In Python, how can I parse the command line, edit the resulting parsed arguments object and generate a valid command line back with the updated values?

For instance, I would like `python cmd.py --foo=bar --step=0` call `python cmd.py --foo=bar --step=1` with all the original `--foo=bar` arguments, potentially without extra arguments added when default value is used.

Is it possible with `argparse`?

Comment: Yes, use arg parse and do `args.step = 1`

Comment: I means, I want to get the exact string object `cmd --foo=bar --step=1` at the end of the day, cause I will send it to a job manager.

Comment: You need to explain how you call your script with these parameters. Because I'm assuming this is not the full "execution" string? You need `Python <script>` first?

Comment: You can think about `cmd` as `python cmd.py`. Just assumed the `#!/usr/bin/python` and `chmod +x` to be here.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there is no way to do this, the parsing is a one-way trip. Why do you think you need the raw argument string again?

Comment: I need the raw argument script to recursively call the command though my job manager. The parsing is a one way trip but the parser almost contains the right information to do the trip back. It could be especially usefull when escaping is needed.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `argparse` to parse the command-line arguments, and then modify those as desired. At the moment however, `argparse` lacks the functionality to work in reverse and convert those values back into a command-line string.  There is however a package for doing precisely that, called [`argunparse`](https://github.com/mbdevpl/argunparse).  For example, the following code in `cmd.py`

```
import sys
import argparse
import argunparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
unparser = argunparse.ArgumentUnparser()
parser.add_argument('--foo')
parser.add_argument('--step', type=int)

kwargs = vars(parser.parse_args())
kwargs['step'] += 1
prefix = f'python {sys.argv[0]} '
arg_string = unparser.unparse(**kwargs)
print(prefix + arg_string)
```

will print the desired command line:

```
python cmd.py --foo=bar --step=1
```

Answer (score 1):

`argparse` is clearly designed to go one way, from `sys.argv` to the `args` namespace.  No thought has been given to preserving information that would let you map things back the other way, much less do the mapping itself.

In general, multiple `sys.argv` could produce the same `args`.  You could, for example, have several arguments that have the same `dest`.  Or you can repeat 'optionals'.  But for a restricted 'parser' setup there may be enough information to recreate a usable `argv`.

Try something like:

```
parser = argparser.ArgumentParser()
arg1 = parser.add_argument('--foo', default='default')
arg2 = parser.add_argument('bar', nargs=2)
```

and then examine the `arg1` and `arg2` objects.  They contain all the information that you supplied to the `add_argument` method.  Of course you could have defined those values in your own data structures before hand, e.g.

```
{'option_string':'--foo', 'default':'default'}
{'dest':'bar', 'nargs':2}
```

and used those as input to `add_argument`.

While the parser may have enough information to recreate a useable `sys.argv`, you have to figure out how to do that yourself.

`default=argparse.SUPPRESS` may be handy.  It keeps the parser from adding a default entry to the namespace.  So if the option isn't used, it won't appear in the namespace.

Comment: Thank you! `argparse` is indeed not injective. Maybe I am looking for another argument parsing module that have been though for this. I actually don't need something very complicated, and don't use all the advanced features of `argparse` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible in any easy way that I know of, then again I've never needed to do this.

But with the lack of information in the question in regards to how you call your script, I'll assume the following:

```
python test.py cmd --foo=bar --step=0
```

And what you could do is do:

```
from sys import argv
for index in range(1, len(argv)): # the first object is the script itself
    if '=' in argv[index]:
        param, value = argv[index].split('=', 1)
        if param == '--step':
            value = '1'
        argv[index] = param + '=' + value

print(argv)
```

Note that this is very specific to `--step` and may be what you've already thought of and just wanted a "better way", but again, I don't think there is.

Comment: Well, thanks but if it's about reimplementing the `argparse` module (that you might want to check out btw) it would be a little painfull. I now how to do that technically, I am just looking for the *clean way* to do it.

Comment: @Lithy Heh I know argparse well enough, but thank you. My point is that no, there's no way of reassembling `argparse` back into a string. You'd have to do manual work here I'm afraid. I might be wrong, but I've never seen code before that does that in my 10 years of Python programming. But I do hope I'm proved wrong by someone more senior : )

Comment: Ok, excuse me. I am just very surprised that nobody ever needed it. It seems like a natural way to send parallel jobs to other machines like though SSH.

Comment: @Lithy Sure, your need is valid. But ask yourself, why do you need to modify `step` in the first place? Could it be that this variable should not be a parameter but rather a increment or static value within the script instead? Or a static variable within the script that changes depending on a different parameter such as `--mod-step`? I've sent parallel jobs numerous of times through Python->SSH, just never had to modify command line parameters in order to do the job i needed. I'm intrigued to know why you would need to change `step` because I will literally learn something, if you don't mind.

Comment: Well, this was a simplified example for the sake of clarity. To be more specific, I want my first call of the script recursively call itself several times in parellel, as in a "map" step. I want to modify a `--process-range` parameter (and not just `--step`) whose value is dynamically computed during the init step.

Answer (score 0):

depending on the scope, this works at the same module at least:

```
pprint(argparse._sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the other answers, rebuilding is imperfect, but if you aren't doing anything too fancy and are okay with imperfect, something like this could work for you as a starting point:

```
def unparse_args(parser, parsed_args):
    """Unparse argparsed args"""
    positional_args = [action.dest
                       for action in parser._actions
                       if not action.option_strings]
    optionals = []
    positionals = []
    for key, value in vars(parsed_args).items():
        if not value:
            # none and false flags go away
            continue
        elif key in positional_args:
            positionals.append(value)
        elif value is True:
            optionals.append(f"--{key}")
        else:
            optionals.append(f"--{key}={value}")
    return " ".join(optionals + positionals)
```

Here's an example using this with a `git clone` clone:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='A sample git clone wrapper')
# options
parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose", action="store_true",
                    help="be more verbose")
parser.add_argument("-q", "--quiet", action="store_true",
                    help="be more quiet")
parser.add_argument("--recurse-submodules", nargs='?',
                    help="initialize submodules in the clone")
parser.add_argument("--recursive", nargs='?',
                    help="alias of --recurse-submodules")
parser.add_argument("-b", "--branch",
                    help=" checkout <branch> instead of the remote's HEAD")
parser.add_argument("--depth", type=int,
                    help="create a shallow clone of that depth")
parser.add_argument("--shallow-submodules", action="store_true",
                    help="any cloned submodules will be shallow")
# positional
parser.add_argument("repo", help="The git repo to clone")
parser.add_argument("dir", nargs='?',help="The location to clone the repo")

# make a fake call to your git clone clone and parse the args
cmdargs = ["--depth=1", "-q", "ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh"]
parsedargs = parser.parse_args(cmdargs)

# now unparse them
unparsed = unparse_args(parser, parsedargs)
print(unparsed)
```